# Select dropdown option at the time of document load using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to select **dropdown**  option at the time of *document load* using Jquery?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#select-Id').val("rightVal");

});
```

Example:
For

```
<select id='days'>
<option value="sun">Sunday</option>
<option value="mon">Monday</option>
</select>
```

Use below code to select Monday

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#days').val("mon");

});
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<select id="sel">
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**Jquery:**

​

```
$(document)​.ready(function(){


    $('#sel').val('2');


    })​;​
```

**[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/333EX/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#sel').val('myValue'); // to set the current value
   var selectedvalue=$('#selectId').val(); // get the selected value
   alert(selectedvalue); 
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/ezituh/1/edit).